# Link Buttons Not redirecting in ie11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms

In IE11 there seems to be an issue where on the click it does nothing at all. I know for a regular button all you have to do is add the name property.  Is it the same for a linkbutton in ie?
I have many of these across my site that will not work correctly now.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="Contact" OnClick="Submit_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: For some reason it wasnt showing its there.

Comment: did you check other factors ? like whether java-script is enabled or not and do all link buttons having same behavior ?

Comment: all the link buttons act the same. On every other browser it works perfectly. Even IE 10

Comment: inspect the element in the F12 tools. See if there is any JavaScript generated by the control. Also check the console to see if any errors are logged. If it just generates a normal anchor tag it should be fine. But with the OnClick property I am thinking there is probably some bad javascript being generated.